# Can I access req (like req.body) in custom error handler in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to write an express middleware, where I log certain req and res headers and write it to an external database.

Part of this is throwing a custom error handler, where I can write my err.stack, err.message, req.body, req.params and req.url to an external file or application.

I tried making my own errorhandler and call it last in app.use() hierarchy. In my routes I throw a new error, and in my custom error handler, I try to log the error and the req.body. However, nothing gets logged except for the error.

app.js

```
app.use(responseTime());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(multilogger({extended: false, development: true, interval: 5000}));
app.use(multiError);

app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

random route

```
router.post("/", function(req, res, next) {
  return next(new Error("Oh no!"));
});
```

Custom Error

```
module.exports = function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.message); //only this gets logged
    console.error(req.body); // this doesn't appear
    next(err);
};
```

I want to destructure the req object of my API Call inside my custom error handler so I can do other things with it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: put this in your `console.error(req.body)` random route and see if it logs

Comment: Where do you inject `Custom Error` to expess app?

Comment: At the end, before the router. `app.use(multierror);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're experiencing this because Express evaluates all middleware/routes in the order they have been added to Express. Calling `next()` literally means, "go to the next possible handler that matches this request". In most cases there is only one route that matches a requested URI, that means the next possible handler would be a handler that has no route specified.

In Express, you define the Default Error Handler & 404 Handler without routes, **after** all other middleware/routes. The 404 Handler should always be the last route inside your Express App.

The Default Error Handler is also a special middleware because it accepts 4 parameters, the first being the error. Its important to check if the error is defined because Express will invoke the Default Error Handler if no route is matched since it doesn't have a route specified. That is why the 404 Handler always goes after Default Error Handler since it is the catch all for any requests that didn't match a route and there would be no error in those cases.

Read more about [Writing Middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html), [Using Middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.error-handling) & [Error  Handling](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) in Express.

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 1337

// not sure where this is in your code based on question info
const indexRouter = require('./indexRouter') 

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

// Your Router
app.use('/', indexRouter)

// Default Error Handler
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // This is necessary to detect any unmatched routes that should be a 404
  if (!err) {
    return next()
  }

  // Handle Error and Respond
})

// 404 Handler, No Route Defined Matched the Requested Route
app.use((req, res) => res.sendStatus(404))

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${Port}`))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanation was really helpfull, and my mistake was indeed that my error middleware was the last one of the middlewares, but still before the app.use(route); Placing it at the end solved the problem for me. Thank you @peteb!